Azure Service Bus | AMQPS | Unstable Every month | Unknown error from remote peer
It happens yesterday too and message starts from following:
2024-09-19 23:36:18.880  INFO 1776090 --- [569306cb73d7:39] org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsSession           : A JMS MessageConsumer has been closed: JmsConsumerInfo: { ID:45157fc8-58d2-44d9-b552-569306cb73d7:39:1:1, destination = s-ataccama-generalsupplier }
2024-09-19 23:36:18.880  WARN 1776090 --- [569306cb73d7:39] o.a.qpid.jms.util.QpidJMSThreadFactory   : Thread: QpidJMS Connection Executor: ID:45157fc8-58d2-44d9-b552-569306cb73d7:39 failed due to an uncaught exception: null

After these two lines there is following stack trace:
   2024-09-19 23:36:18.881  INFO 1776090 --- [plierContact-36] o.s.j.c.CachingConnectionFactory         : Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
    
    javax.jms.JMSException: Unknown error from remote peer
            at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProviderException.toJMSException(ProviderException.java:34) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
            at org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions.JmsExceptionSupport.create(JmsExceptionSupport.java:80) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
            at org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions.JmsExceptionSupport.create(JmsExceptionSupport.java:112) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
            at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection.pull(JmsConnection.java:915) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
            at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection.pull(JmsConnection.java:899) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
            at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsMessageConsumer.performPullIfRequired(JmsMessageConsumer.java:732) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
            at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsMessageConsumer.dequeue(JmsMessageConsumer.java:304) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
            at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsMessageConsumer.receive(JmsMessageConsumer.java:213) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
            at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:132) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:431) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:316) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:270) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1237) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
            at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120) ~[spring-jms-5.3.23.jar!/:5.3.23]
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
    Caused by: org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProviderException: Unknown error from remote peer
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpSupport.convertToNonFatalException(AmqpSupport.java:184) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpAbstractResource.processRemoteClose(AmqpAbstractResource.java:269) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpProvider.processUpdates(AmqpProvider.java:985) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpProvider.onData(AmqpProvider.java:871) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.transports.netty.NettyTcpTransport$NettyTcpTransportHandler.channelRead0(NettyTcpTransport.java:563) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.qpid.jms.transports.netty.NettyTcpTransport$NettyTcpTransportHandler.channelRead0(NettyTcpTransport.java:556) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar!/:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar!/:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar!/:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar!/:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1373) ~[netty-handler-4.1.82.Final.jar!/:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1236) ~[netty-handler-4.1.82.Final.jar!/:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285) ~[netty-handler-4.1.82.Final.jar!/:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:519) ~[netty-codec-4.1.82.Final.jar!/:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:458) ~[netty-codec-4.1.82.Final.jar!/:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:280) ~[netty-codec-4.1.82.Final.jar!/:4.1.82.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.82.Final.jar!/:4.1.82.Final]

After this i get following logs:
2024-09-19 23:36:18.992  WARN 1776090 --- [plierContact-36] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 's-ataccama-generalsupplier' - trying to recover. Cause: Unknown error from remote peer
2024-09-19 23:36:19.278  INFO 1776090 --- [windows.net:-1]] org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection        : Connection ID:8405d717-54fd-49e9-ad40-534f6f3c2548:40 connected to server: amqps://tietoator.servicebus.windows.net
2024-09-19 23:36:39.714  WARN 1776090 --- [windows.net:-1]] o.a.q.j.p.a.b.AmqpResourceBuilder        : Open of resource:(JmsConsumerInfo: { ID:8405d717-54fd-49e9-ad40-534f6f3c2548:40:1:1, destination = s-ataccama-generalsupplier }) failed: The service was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101 TrackingId:bc369da39d964bc39c6bf63281bd3182_G16, SystemTracker:gateway10, Timestamp:2024-09-19T21:36:39 [condition = amqp:internal-error]

and also
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProviderException: The service was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101 TrackingId:bc369da39d964bc39c6bf63281bd3182_G16, SystemTracker:gateway10, Timestamp:2024-09-19T21:36:39 [condition = amqp:internal-error] 2024-09-19 23:36:44.866  WARN 1776090 --- [plierContact-37] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 's-ataccama-generalsupplier' - trying to recover. Cause: The service was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101 TrackingId:bc369da39d964bc39c6bf63281bd3182_G16, SystemTracker:gateway10, Timestamp:2024-09-19T21:36:39 [condition = amqp:internal-error]

Using Standard Service Bus with Spring Boot JMS:
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

This error comes twice a month and some poor people like me are searching this for an year :-)
https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/issues/424

Increase the idleTimeout and sessionTimeout in the connection factory configuration and also Implement more aggressive retry policy or extend the retry interval in the JMS listener configuration.

The error message indicates a service error.  It may be service idle timeout, which you cannot control from your code, or it may be another issue with the resource itself.  You'll need the Service Bus service team to analyze this.  Your best path forward is to open an Azure support ticket: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request
